# Solving Trapezoid and finding the length of its line

Tags: geometry

copy the trapezoid on the answer sheet and draw line around it so each point on the line has a distance of 0.5 m to the boundary of trapezoid.

[image: Please check this image]

I found this question on my sample paper of entrance exam and I dont know how do I make lines and how to calculate them.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: What happens is at the corners of this trapezoid, you form a path of arcs that can be combined into a circle with $r = 0.5$ m. Hence, the length of the line is simply the parameter of the trapezoid plus the parameter of the circle. (Try to think of the definition of a circle: a set of points that are at a fixed distance to the center!)

Comment: so how do I calculate all of them?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose by distance from boundary, it is meant shortest distance.

- Around corners, you will have circular arcs with radius as $0.5m$
- Straight lines parallel to sides at distance of $0.5m$ from it.

[image]

To calculate length of the line, observe that you need length equal to perimeter of trapoziod plus only the perimeter of a circe with radius $0.5$, as angle subtended by arc at any vertex is equal to  $180^o - \text{interior angle}$ at that vertex.

So total angle subtended at all vertex comes out to be $360^o$, ie we need only $2\times \pi\times 0.5$ curved length.

Thus required length is:

$$(8+2\sqrt{2})+(2\times0.5\pi)\\=8+ 2\sqrt 2 + \pi$$